# Adding (Nolock) After All Select Statements in All Stored Procedures by writing a script in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I have many stored procedures in the database and if the stored procedures have select stataments in it, I want to add (Nolock) after all these select statements by writing a script.

I can get all stored procedures by using cursor and sys tables but I didnt figure out how to find exactly select stataments and adding nolock after them.

I need your nice ideas.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... I wouldn't do that; adding `NOLOCK` everywhere is a SQL Anti-Pattern.

There's other ways to achieve the same effect:

1. Adjust Transaction Isolation Level for your applications that call your database, and set them to `READ UNCOMMITTED`, which would have the same effect as adding `NOLOCK` to all of your `SELECT` statements... See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189542.aspx
2. Or implement `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT` mode for the entire database: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345124%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

In fact, our very own Jeff Atwood wrote about the same issue that you're likely trying to solve here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/deadlocked.html

If possible, I'd go with option #2, but either of these options will probably be less work up front as well as going forward.

Comment: `NOLOCK` is, indeed, something to only be used in special circumstances.